Maytag Dishwasher MDB4949SHZ0 food particles clogging wash arms almost every cycle
Despite pre-rinsing all of my dishes, the spray arms are constantly clogging with food particles. Often it's pieces of cabbage, a grain of rice, or similar. The top arm clogs more often but the lower one does occasionally also. The dishwasher is about 6 years old.
I disassembled the dishwasher as much as I could from the inside and there's no real filter. There's a plastic grate that is extremely coarse and would let something corn or pea-sized through. At first glance, this seems like a grotesque failure in machine design. (The owner's manual advertises a "maintenance free hard food disposer".) My next conclusion is that the hard food disposer has degraded or failed.
Any suggestions or troubleshooting would be appreciated.

You need to clean the internal pipework as at some point the food got past the filter that you should clean regularly. Either it is damaged or incorrectly fitted.

@SolarMike There is no proper filter, just the coarse plastic grate. The openings are huge but it's not damaged.

If already prerinsing, adding some dishwashing detergent and washing the dishes will save using the dishwasher.

@crip659 it's true, but there has to be a reason the machine is performing so poorly. I can't imagine it was designed this way. I suspect the chopper / "hard food disposer" is damaged but wanted an evaluation from someone with more experience.

Finally took the machine apart for diagnosis. The chopper/macerator had disintegrated completely. The new one is in and while I have not finished a load of dishes yet I am almost certain it will resolve the problem.
All four blades were missing and it had torn away from the perforated disk-shaped piece.


